# Name of function which similar to characteristic function.

Tags: terminology, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of subset $A$ of set $X$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
I_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\in A\\
0&x\not\in A
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

What the name function which defined by
\begin{align*}
\ldots_A(x)=
\begin{cases}
1&x\not\in A\\
0&x\in A
\end{cases}
?
\end{align*}
(which similar to characteristic functions)

Comment: It is simply the characteristic function of the complement of $A$.

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy says, it's just $I_{\complement A} = 1 - I_A.$